# cannot delete or update in parent rows

Tags: mysql

I'm a new user. I would like to ask an error I face in my assignment project. I create `room_type_ID` that is a primary key in Room Type Table. Then, `room_type_id` is included in room table as foreign key. The problem is if I typed one of room type id as RI2 instead of RT2. When I tried to change it in Update query in room table, it shows cant update on child row foreign key constraint fails. But, it show cant update on parent row a foreign key constraint fail in room type table. I'm sorry for my English since it's not my primary language

```sql
create table room_type (
room_type varchar(20) not null,
room_type_id varchar(10) not null,
primary key(room_type_id));
```

```sql
create table room (
room_no varchar(10) not null,
building_id  varchar(10) not null,
room_type_id varchar(10) not null,
room_price varchar(10) not null,
primary key(room_no),
foreign key (building_id) references
building(building_id),
foreign key (room_type_id) references
room_type(room_type_id));
```

```sql
insert into room_type
values ('Standard Room', 'RT1'),
('Dulexe Room', 'RI2'),
('Super Dulexe Room', 'RT3'),
('Suite Room', 'RT4'),
('Super Suite Room', 'RT5'),
('Executive Suite Room', 'RT6'),
('Presidential Suite Room', 'RT7'),
('Family Room', 'RT8'),
('VIP Room', 'RT9'),
('Ceremony Hall 1', 'RT10'),
('Ceremony Hall 2', 'RT11'),
('Ceremony Hall 3', 'RT12'),
('Meeting Conference Room 1', 'RT13'),
('Meeting Conference Hall 1', 'RT14'),
('Meeting COnference Hall 2', 'RT15');
```

```sql
insert into room
values ('R101', 'B1', 'RT1', '$100'),
('R102', 'B1', 'RT1', '$100'),
('R103', 'B1', 'RT1', '$100'),
('R107', 'B1', 'RI2',  '$150'),
('R108', 'B1', 'RI2', '$150'),
('R1011','B1', 'RT3', '$180'),
('R1012','B1', 'RT3',  '$180'),
('R1013','B1', 'RT3', '$180'),
('R1014','B1', 'RT3','$180'),
('R501', 'B5', 'RT4',  '$250'),
('R502', 'B5', 'RT4',  '$250'),
('R505', 'B5', 'RT5',  '$350'),
('R506', 'B5', 'RT5',  '$350'),
('R601', 'B6', 'RT4',  '$250'),
('R602', 'B6', 'RT4',  '$250'),
('R605', 'B6', 'RT5',  '$350'),
('R606', 'B6', 'RT5', '$350'),
('R701', 'B7', 'RT6', '$480'),
('R702', 'B7', 'RT6', '$480'),
('R801', 'B8', 'RT7',  '$550'),
('R802', 'B8', 'RT7',  '$550'),
('R901', 'B9', 'RT8',  '$380'),
('R902', 'B9', 'RT8',  '$380'),
('R1001','B10','RT9',  '$650'),
('R1002','B10','RT9',  '$650'),
('R1101','B11','RT10',  '$800'),
('R1102','B11','RT11',  '$800'),
('R1103','B11','RT12',  '$800'),
('R1201','B12','RT13',  '$700'),
('R1202','B12','RT14',  '$700'),
('R1203','B12','RT15',  '$700');
```

```sql
Update room
set room_type_id='RT2'
where room_no='R107';
```

```sql
Update room
set room_type_id='RT2'
where room_no='R108', building_id='B1';
```

```sql
Update room_type
set room_type_id = 'RT2'
where room_type='Dulexe Room';
```

Comment: bro you did a typo .... look ('Dulexe Room', 'RI2'),  --> you meant RT2 instead of  RI2 i think. you DONT have RT2 on your room types i see

Comment: *`set room_type_id='RT2'`* - no such room_type_id; *`where room_no='R108', building_id='B1';`* incorrect syntax, use AND and not a comma; *`room_type varchar(20) not null,`* too short for shown data; *`foreign key (building_id) references building(building_id),`* - the table DDL not provided. Resume: you're too inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key constraint fails because in your `room_type` table you don't have a row with `room_type_id='RT2'`

Additionally, if you have rows in `room` with a specific `room_type_id`, you can't change that in the `room_type` table. In order to do that you can do the following steps:

1. Add a new row with the correct `room_type_id` in `room_type`
2. Update the problematic rows in `room` to have the new `room_type_id`
3. Delete the row with the wrong `room_type_id` from `room_type`